# Binding JSON Results with Complex Object with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given this module and controller

```
angular.module('contactServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('ApiKey', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/V1/apikeys', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
    });
});

function ContactCtrl($scope, ApiKey) {
    $scope.keys = ApiKey.query();
}
```

which returns this data

```
{ myObject: [{ id: "1", value: "Value1" }, { id: "2", value: "Value2" },    { id: "3", value: "Value3" }] }
```

to this html element

```
<select style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option ng-repeat="k in keys" value="{{k.id}}" >{{k.value}}</option>
</select>
```

When the page loads the resource grabs the data, but it returns a promise,  which I understand conceptually, and can see that it has returned data (at a later time than the loading of the page), but the select is never loaded. At one point, I had used the $http service and had this working, but that was some time ago and I really like to use the resource abstraction if possible.

Thank you,
Stephen

**Update**

Based on the comments here is the updated working example. The actual fix was to grab the json object and look for the apiKeys object.

```
<select ng-model="keys" ng-options="k.value for k in keys"></select>


function ContactCtrl($scope, ApiKey) {
    ApiKey.query({}, function (data) {
        $scope.keys = data.apiKeys; <<<<<<<<<<========= the fix
    });
}
```

Comment: Off topic, but I believe Angular prefers the select ng-options attribute instead of ng-repeat on the option element.

Comment: BTW do you get any errors from console?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall thank you for pointing me in the right direction, re: select ng-options.

Comment: @artworkadシ No exceptions, just mental lapses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try changing the code to something like this when you are invoking the service layer.

```
    function ContactCtrl($scope, ApiKey) {
        ApiKey.query({}, function(data){
        $scope.keys = data;
      });
    }
```

Bhaskara

Comment: Bhaskara Kempaiah, your answer lead me to the fix that works.